# fusion table more than 5 styles + comparision with MapBox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

My goal is to make a similar functionality but with google maps: http://interaktiv.morgenpost.de/fussballkarte-berlin/#9/52.5605/12.5601
I know that this is done with MapBox.

We have around 12 000 big polygons, KML file is around 96 Mb, so we can not work with drawing polygons. I have some experience with fusion tables from google and wanted to use it. BUT they do not support mouse onhover event.

I fount the js lib fusiontips which gets mouse coordinates and after custom delay sends request to fusion table to get data. He the problem which we can face 25 000 request per day limit.

Also the fusion table layer supports max 5 styles, but I might need to have more.

Than I found this example: http://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col0%2C+col1%2C+col2%2C+col3%2C+col4%2C+col5%2C+col6%2C+col7%2C+col8%2C+col9%2C+col10%2C+col11%2C+col12%2C+col13%2C+col14%2C+col15%2C+col16%2C+col17%2C+col18%2C+col19%2C+col20%2C+col21%2C+col22+from+628653+&h=false&lat=51.502758957640296&lng=-0.00823974609375&z=12&t=1&l=col0

And now my question:
1. How MapBox supports mouse onhover event? Does it also sent in background requests to data storage? Limits?

2. How I can I go over limit for fusion tables?
3. How the last example is implemented? I checked the code but could not get how did they make so many styles... I checked original fusion table and the style is not there..

Thank you for any help

Comment: You can have as many colors for polygons as you want if you set them up in the FusionTables User Interface (define the color of the polygon using a column in the FusionTable).

Comment: Wow thank you! So I add special colomn to Fusion table and how can I use it for visualization? I use Google maps API, not FT API.gemTable = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: activeMap,
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: gem_table_id
        },
       styles: [{
           {   where: "'description' <= 2000000",
        polygonOptions: {
            strokeColor: '#FFF333', strokeWeight: 1, strokeOpacity: 0.32, fillColor: '#FFF333', fillOpacity: 0.30
        }
    },
    {   where: ....   so I can use as much as I need colors?

Comment: https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2681556

Comment: thank you. this I also found. Got problems with zoom level < 3 cause some areas are not shown and I have holes..

Comment: today started to work with mapbox.. for now, its very very buggy